# Virtual DOM and react performance query?

Tags: reactjs, virtual-dom

If I have a parent component which contains multiple child components and if I update parent component will react re-render the whole parent including child??

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will re-render all nested child components by default. However under the hood react applies diffing algorithm to determine what dom nodes needs to be finally updated. In most cases this diffing is sufficient and fast enough. If you experience performance problems, take look at lifecycle method [`shouldComponentUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) where you can define whether component (and it's childs) will be re-rendered or not.

For example if you want to re-render component only when `myProp` changes:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.props.myProp !== nextProps.myProp) {
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Thats what I am trying to understand, what is the need of creating virtual DOM, consuming memory, implementing diffing algorithm. I mean where does react really shines. I think If react re-renders the whole parent component including child then DOM manipulation is also not that slow/bad.